# How to make February count as 30 working days

Tags: sql, sql-server

This code calculates the amount of days given a date range, taking into account the day the employee was hired. If the Employee was hired inside the selected date range it takes it out from the day the employee started to the final date that the user states.

I want it to take February as 30 working days, yet it always takes it out as 28 working days. In general I just want to validate if it's February and the employee has worked the 28 or 29 days in the month to take it out as 30 working days.

I've tried to add another `WHEN` to the code like this:

```
WHEN s.FechaInicio <= DATEADD(day, -1, EOMONTH(@FechaInicio)) AND (s.FechaFin >= DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(@FechaInicio)) AND s.FechaFin <= @FechaFin) then DATEDIFF(day, DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(@FechaInicio)), @FechaFin)+1
```

I have a feeling I would have to use nested Case statements but have no clue on how they should go or look

Here's an image of that I mean: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ9Ee.png)

The date range used there is:

```
DECLARE @FechaInicio DATE = '2023-02-01'
DECLARE @FechaFin DATE = '2023-02-28'
```

I want it to come out like this: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg1gL.png)

Date range used here:

```
DECLARE @FechaInicio DATE = '2023-03-01'
DECLARE @FechaFin DATE = '2023-03-30'
```

Here's the complete code:

```
SELECT e.IdEmpleado,e.Nombres,s.FechaInicio,s.FechaFin,s.EstadoFila, 
    CASE
    WHEN s.FechaInicio > @FechaInicio AND (s.FechaFin < @FechaFin ) then (DATEDIFF(DAY,s.FechaInicio,@FechaFin)+1)
    WHEN s.FechaInicio > @FechaInicio AND (s.FechaFin > @FechaFin ) then ((DATEDIFF(DAY,s.FechaInicio,@FechaFin)))
    WHEN s.FechaInicio <= @FechaInicio AND (s.FechaFin > @FechaFin OR s.FechaFin is null) then DATEDIFF(day, @FechaInicio, @FechaFin)+1
    --WHEN s.FechaInicio >= @FechaFin AND s.FechaInicio <  @FechaInicio  then DATEDIFF(DAY,@FechaFin,s.FechaInicio)

    ELSE 0
    END AS DiasTrabajados
FROM contratacion.Contrato s
INNER JOIN contratacion.Empleados e ON s.IdEmpleado = e.IdEmpleado
WHERE s.EstadoFila = 1
```

Any contribution to the problem resolution would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Months have differing numbers of days in them so anything you're doing already needs to account for that. What are you trying to accomplish by treating a month as having a differing number of days than it actually has?

Comment: @BenThul It is very common (especially in accrual methods, scheduling and/or forecasting)  to use 30 over 360  vs actual over actual.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - that's fair (and thank you for shedding some light there), but I think my statement still stands in that context. Which is to say - if you're already treating every month like it has 30 days (regardless of how many it actually has), why is February special? Whatever is being done to pretend that May has 30d in it should be amortizable to Feb, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you really do just want to output "30" as the number of days in any instance where the employee has worked the "full" month (based on your date range parameters), then my suggestion is just don't worry about doing the DATEDIFF in that particular instance.

```
SELECT e.IdEmpleado,e.Nombres,s.FechaInicio,s.FechaFin,s.EstadoFila, 
    CASE
    WHEN s.FechaInicio > @FechaInicio AND (s.FechaFin < @FechaFin ) then (DATEDIFF(DAY,s.FechaInicio,@FechaFin)+1)
    WHEN s.FechaInicio > @FechaInicio AND (s.FechaFin > @FechaFin ) then ((DATEDIFF(DAY,s.FechaInicio,@FechaFin)))
    /* don't bother with the DATEDIFF on this next comparison - just output 30 */
    WHEN s.FechaInicio <= @FechaInicio AND (s.FechaFin >= @FechaFin OR s.FechaFin is null) then 30 -- DATEDIFF(day, @FechaInicio, @FechaFin)+1
    ELSE 0
    END AS DiasTrabajados
FROM contratacion.Contrato s
INNER JOIN contratacion.Empleados e ON s.IdEmpleado = e.IdEmpleado
WHERE s.EstadoFila = 1
```